# chrome declarativeNetRequest added dynamic rules not working

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-declarativenetrequest

I have this code in my chrome extension backround.js file

```js
const bannedHosts = [];

const setupContextMenus = () => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: 'blockHost',
        type: 'normal',
        contexts: ['all'],
        title: 'Block website',
    })

    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: 'unblockHost',
        type: 'normal',
        contexts: ['all'],
        title: 'Unblock website',
    })
}


chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener( () => {
    console.log('extension installed')
    setupContextMenus()
})

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener( ( clickData) => {
    if( clickData.menuItemId === 'blockHost' ) {
        console.log(clickData)
        bannedHosts.push(clickData.pageUrl)
        
        chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
            removeRuleIds: bannedHosts.map((h, i) => i + 1),
            addRules: bannedHosts.map((h, i) => ({
                id: i + 1,
                action: {type: 'redirect', redirect: {extensionPath: '/options.html'}},
                condition: {urlFilter: `||${h}/`, resourceTypes: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame']},
            }))
        });
        console.log(bannedHosts)
    } else if( clickData.menuItemId === 'unblockHost' ) {
      ...
    }
})
```

I'm doing a quick test of the code by installing the extension, I'm able to see the context menu voices and I'm able to track the click event. My problem is with the `declarativeNerRequest`, I've noticed that when an url is added to the array `blockedHosts`, the rule that I want to add that is supposed to redirect the user to the options page will not work and if I try to visit the website it will be displayed instead of redirecting the user.

I have declared the correct permission in manifest v3, how I can fix this problem? How I add correctly a new url and a rule to block it and how I can remove the related url and rule if needed?

manifest file

```js
import { defineManifest } from '@crxjs/vite-plugin'

export default defineManifest({
  name: '',
  description: '',
  version: '1.0.0',
  manifest_version: 3,
  icons: {
    16: 'img/logo-16.png',
    32: 'img/logo-34.png',
    48: 'img/logo-48.png',
    128: 'img/logo-128.png',
  },
  action: {
    // default_popup: 'popup.html',
    // default_icon: 'img/logo-48.png',
  },
  options_page: 'options.html',
  background: {
    service_worker: 'src/background/index.js',
    type: 'module',
  },
  content_scripts: [
    {
      matches: ['http://*/*', 'https://*/*'],
      js: ['src/content/index.js'],
    },
  ],
  host_permissions: [
    '<all_urls>'
  ],
  web_accessible_resources: [
    {
      resources: [
        'img/logo-16.png', 
        'img/logo-34.png', 
        'img/logo-48.png', 
        'img/logo-128.png',
        'options.html'
      ],
      matches: [
        '<all_urls>'
      ],
    },
  ],
  permissions: [
    'tabs',
    'contextMenus',
    'webRequest',
    'webRequestBlocking',
    'declarativeNetRequest'
  ]
})
```

Comment: 1) Declare options.html in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/). 2) Add `"<all_urls>"` in "host_permissions" in manifest.json or use [optional_host_permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/permissions/).

Comment: I already have the `host_permissions` set on `<all_urls>`, maybe I need to add the options page to the web accessible resources where at the moment I didn't set nothing

Comment: @wOxxOm I've tried to rebuild the extension but there is no way to make it working

Comment: clickData.pageUrl is not a host, it's a URL. Use `new URL(clickData.pageUrl).hostname` or change `urlFilter` if you want to block the exact page.

Comment: @wOxxOm ok, I will test your suggestion. I want to block the whole site not the single url.

Comment: @wOxxOm now that I've used the ´new URL()´ function to extract the hostname the new added sites are blocked correctly and the page I want to display is loaded. The problem is to remove the host, is there any way?

Comment: Use chrome.declarativeNetRequest.getDynamicRules, find the entry for the host in its result, then use chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules with that rule's id in removeRuleIds parameter.